# What is the meaning of "Why else would she?" in this context?

Tags: meaning

> I have told my husband it makes me very uncomfortable and that it almost seems she attends hoping to run into him. **Why else would she?**

Would someone explain what the part in bold means please?

Answer (score 5):

This is a more-or-less idiomatic construct. ***Why else would she?*** should be interpreted as ***What other reason (besides ...) is there for her to ...*** - in this case, ***What other reason (besides hoping to run into him) is there for her to attend?***. Note that this is referring to an action and associated reason identified in the previous sentence: *I have told my husband it makes me very uncomfortable and that it almost seems **she attends hoping to run into him.***

Comment: Unless there's some unspecified prior context that could reasonably serve as the "deleted" main verb after the question (such as the speaker's husband having just asked his wife *Why is that woman here?*), I think it's semantically and syntactically shaky to assume the missing verb is ***attend***. Strictly speaking, and given only the context we've been provided above, I would say the deleted element is *Why else would she **have run into him**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - The original, edited out by Lambie (incorrectly, in my opinion) was ***I have told my husband it makes me very uncomfortable and that it almost seems she attends hoping to run into him. Why else would she?***

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Note that I had preserved the original in my answer.

Comment: oic. I hadn't noticed that. Yes, unquestionably your interpretation is the most natural given the exact original. So I must fully endorse your answer (and edit reversal) and actually upvote you. Not that I meaningfully *disagreed* with the answer in the first place. It just seemed to me there was an element of ambiguity in OP's text as I read it at the time, and I (mistakenly, obviously) thought I might usefully prod you into acknowledging that in the actual answer text.